# Как найти максимальный элемент массива, между индексами?

Tags: c++

```
    void Fill(int arr[], const int size);
int Max(int arr[], const int size);
float AverageFunc(int arr[], const int size);



void PrintArray(int arr[], const int size);
int main()
{
    int const size = 10;
    int const size1 = 7;
    int arr [size];

    srand(time(0));

    Fill(arr, size);
    PrintArray(arr, size);


    cout <<"Average -> "<< AverageFunc(arr, size) << endl;
    cout <<"Max -> "<< Max(arr, size) << endl;

}

void Fill(int arr[], const int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = rand() % 33 - 12;
    }
}

int Max(int arr[], const int size)
{
    int max = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] > max)
        {
            max = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}

float AverageFunc(int arr[], const int size)
{
    int sum = 0;
    float average = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        sum += arr[i];
    }
    average = float(sum / size);
    return average;
}

void PrintArray(int arr[], const int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout <<"["<<i<<"]"<<setw(2)<< arr[i] << endl;;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: В вашей (?) функции `Max` - ошибка. Первоначальное значение должно быть значением первого элемента массива. А чтобы найти между индексами можно поменять числа в `for`. Там уже сейчас 0 и `size`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Передайте в переменную элемент массива и  сравнивайте при каждой итерации, написав условие.

Comment: Как именно это сделать? 
я начинающий и еще не особо понимаю это все

Comment: @that_drowning_man Вы желаете получить максимальное значение из массива верно?

Comment: Мне в задачи написано "найти максимальный элемент массива, между двумя индексами " а как это написать... я не понимаю

Comment: Пример:
Переменная мах равна элементу массива, затем запускайте цикл и пишите условие если массив i  больше мах то присваете в переменную мах.
Условие:
 if arr[i] > max {max = arr[i]}

Comment: у меня так и написано

Comment: только это из всех индексов максимальный

Comment: У Вас мах равен нулю, Int max = 0;

Comment: int Max(int arr[], const int size)
{

 for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
 {
  if (arr[i] > max)
  {
   max = arr[i];
  }
 }
 return max;
}
а потом как?

Comment: @that_drowning_man

int array1[4] = { 2, 10, 5, 6 }; 
    int max = array1[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)  
    {
        if (array1[i]>max) {
            max=array1[i];
            }
    
    }
    return max;

Comment: @that_drowning_man получили мах?

Comment: напишите мне пожалуйста как должно быть, реально не получается

Comment: @that_drowning_man  запустили код который я отправил в качетве примера?

Comment: да, я только не знаю как указать именно индекс в котором искать максимальный элемент

Comment: @that_drowning_man вы же передаете массив который содржить элементы числе, верно?

Comment: Всё разобрался.
int Max(int arr[], const int size)
{
 int start;
 int end;
 cout << "Enter first index";
 cin >> start;
 cout << "Enter last index";
 cin >> end;
 int max = arr[0];
 for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
 {
  if (arr[i] > max)
  {
   max = arr[i];
  }
 }
 return max;
}

Comment: @that_drowning_man успехов вам!

Answer (score 1):

Максимльный элемент массива `arr` между индексами `left` и `right` включительно.

```
int Max(int * arr, int left, int right) {
    if (arr == 0 || left > right || left < 0) throw("Бред");
    int m = arr[left);
    for(int i = left+1; i <= right; ++i)
        if (m < arr[i]) m = arr[i];
    return m;
    }
```